# React-native Side-menu not working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use react-native-sidemenu https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-side-menu
 My code looks like this.
There is no error and even output is overlapping to each other

```
   var list = [{name: "komaldeep", subtitle: "dssdfds", avatar_url:"sadasdsa" }];

  export default class First extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
         this.state = {
           isOpen: false,
        };
       this.toggleSideMenu = this.toggleSideMenu.bind(this);
     }



toggleSideMenu () {
    this.setState({
        isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    })
}

render() {
    //menu list `enter code here`
    const MenuComponent = (
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ededed', paddingTop: 200}}>
            <List containerStyle={{marginBottom: 20}}>

                {
                    list.map((l, i) => (

                        <ListItem
                            roundAvatar
                            onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}
                            avatar={l.avatar_url}
                            key={i}
                            title={l.name}
                            subtitle={l.subtitle}
                        />
                    ))
                }

            </List>
        </View>
    )


    return (

        <SideMenu
            isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
            menu={MenuComponent} >

           //Menu Component just contain some random text
            <Menu toggleSideMenu={this.toggleSideMenu.bind(this)}/>

        </SideMenu>

    );
  }
}
```

Can you just guide me.. what i am doing wrong..

OutPut looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRhaY.png)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the items in your menu shows up on the right of the screen, seemingly outside of the menu, is that your MenuComponent takes up the entire screen. Set the prop `openMenuOffset={number}` to SideMenu and use the same number to set `width: number` in the style of your MenuComponent.